# count in list of dictionaries for IDF

Tags: python, dictionary, count, tf-idf

i have a list of dictionaries of the form

```
list_of_dicts = [{id1: [word1, word2, word3...]}, 
{id1: [word1, word2, word3..]},..]
```

i would like to count the number of occurances of a word throughout the whole list and not just one list of values. Im confused which for-loop structure I should use.

I've tried this:

```
from collections import Counter
count = Counter()
term = ""
for dict in list_of_dicts:
  for key, val in dict.items():
    for word in val:
      term = word
  counter = count[term]
  term = ""
  print(counter)
```

this gives me just zeros.

Any hint how to proceed is greatly appreciated!

Edit: i would like to replace the word in question with its count, 
so for the  example above that would be:
    list_of_dicts = [{id1: [2, 2, 2...]}, 
    {id1: [2, 2, 2..]},..]

Comment: What's the expected output ?

Comment: I woud like to replace the word itself with its count, so a simple number

Comment: Can u add some sample output.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that list contains dictionary object only and each dictionary can have a list of words.

I am not sure, what you are achieving by doing `counter = count(term)` and just above that by setting `search_term`. Seems something missing there.

Anyway I have tried this, and it works.

```
list_of_dicts = [{'id1':['ayush', 'mishra', 'lol']}, {'id2':['ayush', 'mishra2', 'lol']}, {'id3':['ayush2', 'mishra3', 'lol']}]
cnt = 0
target_term = "mishra"
for dict in list_of_dicts:
  for key, val in dict.items():
    for word in val:
      if word == target_term:
        cnt+=1
print(cnt)
```